# How does wireless mobile charging work in BMW 7 series car?

Tags: batteries, automotive, cellphone, wireless-charging

I've seen a video in which the presenter just keeps the phone in some small chamber and closes it for automatic charging of smartphone.[image]

Comment: This has nothing to do with BMW cars series 7 or otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

QI standard wireless charging. Must have a QI compatible phone or adapter (sticker, case, wired adapter which defeats part of the purpose). Any Samsung higher end phone for the last two years has had QI charging coils on the battery. Newer S7 models have fast - wireless charging as well. As with most wireless charging the distance is inches/mm at best. They are intended to sit flay against the charging pad.

Comment: What is the maximum distance for which QI standard charging works effectively?

Comment: Single digit inches. It's supposed to be flat against the charging pad for the highest efficiency.

Comment: Can you please suggest some more reading material on this topic?

Comment: Uhm, enlighten me why you cannot find this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qi_(inductive_power_standard)  on your own ???